# Duda sobre funcion PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Quería saber como hago para crear una función que inserte datos en una tabla.

¿Que valor debo devolver (**return**)?

Con un procedimiento lo hago correctamente, pero a la hora de hacerlo con una función, no entiendo que valor debo devolver.

Comment: Depende "que quieres saber"; es decir si quieres saber si se realizo o fallo (manejando errores como corresponde) digamos 1 para éxito y 0 para fallo; igual de volver un valor "n" dependiendo si se dan diversos escenarios a controlar o hasta donde se llego y claro, el valor retornado "bien conocido" del lado que recibe e interpretara dicho valor.

Answer (score 3):

Para tu caso la forma correcta es por un `procedure` por que no necesitas tener un retorno necesariamente.

Sin embargo la estructura de una `function` es la siguiente.

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION function_name
   [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

   RETURN return_datatype

IS | AS

   [declaration_section]

BEGIN
   executable_section

[EXCEPTION
   exception_section]

END [function_name];
```

Donde `return_datatype` debe devolver necesariamente un valor. Como puede ser 0 en caso de que la ejecución de insertar fue correcta, y en caso de que haya habido una `exception`, devolver un 1, para que el programa que ocupe dicha función, entienda si se realizo o no la inserción del o los datos en dicha tabla.

Si necesitas mas aclaración, ve dejando en los comentarios.

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda. Saludos y éxito en tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que los procedimientos, una función es un fragmento de código PL/SQL, pero la función devuelve un valor. Estas funciones almacenadas se utilizan como las funciones de ORACLE.

**Sintaxis**

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION nombre_función
[(parámetro [IN] tipo, ...)]
RETURN tipo {IS/AS} Bloque PL/SQL;
```

**OR REPLACE**

Si la función existe, se reemplaza su descripción.

**parámetro**

Especifica un parámetro que se pasa como dato de entrada y que se usa como una variable dentro del bloque.

**tipo**

Tipo de parámetro (SQL o PL/SQL).

**RETURN tipo**

Tipo del valor devuelto por la función.

**Ejemplo**

***Función factorial :***

```
CREATE FUNCTION factorial (n IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS BEGIN
      if n = 0 then
           return (1) ;
      else
           return ((n * factorial (n-1))) ; 
      end if ;
END ;
```

***Uso en SQL*Plus:***

```
SQL> select factorial(5) from DUAL;

FACTORIAL(5)
------------
         120

SQL>
```

A partir de la versión 11, es posible indicar a Oracle que conserve en memoria el resultado de la llamada a una función. Cuando se activa esta funcionalidad para una función, cada vez que se llama a esta función con valores diferentes de los parámetros, Oracle almacena en caché el valor de los parámetros y el resultado de la función. Cuando más adelante se llama de nuevo a esta función con los mismos valores de los parámetros, se recupera el resultado de la caché en lugar de calcularlo de nuevo.

Para activar esta funcionalidad para una función, es suficiente...

**Otros ejemplos :**

**1º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_authid2
RETURN NUMBER
AUTHID DEFINED
AS
   x   NUMBER(9,2);
BEGIN
   x := 65400;
   RETURN x;
END;
```

**2º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_cursr
  ( p_job VARCHAR2 )
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   emp_refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_refcur FOR
   SELECT empno, ename
   FROM emp
   WHERE job = p_job;
   RETURN emp_refcur;
END;
```

**3º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_cursr2
  ( p_job VARCHAR2,
    c SYS_REFCURSOR )
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   emp_refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_refcur
   FOR SELECT empno, ename
   FROM emp
   WHERE job = p_job;
   RETURN emp_refcur;
END;
```

**4º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_inout
  ( p_job IN VARCHAR2,
    p_job2 OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_job3 IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   emp_refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_refcur
   FOR SELECT empno, ename
   FROM emp
   WHERE job = p_job;
   RETURN emp_refcur;
END;
```

**5º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_inout2
  ( p_job IN VARCHAR2,
    p_job2 OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
    p_job3 IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   emp_refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_refcur
   FOR SELECT empno, ename
   FROM emp
   WHERE job = p_job;
   RETURN emp_refcur;
END;
```

**6º) Ejemplos**

```
CREATE FUNCTION sal_ok2
  ( salary  NUMBER,
    title   VARCHAR2 )
RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   min_sal NUMBER;
   max_sal NUMBER;
   -- AUTHID CURRENT_USER
   -- PARALLEL_ENABLE
BEGIN
   SELECT losal, hisal
   INTO min_sal, max_sal
   FROM sals
   WHERE job = title;
   RETURN (salary >= min_sal)
      AND (salary <= max_sal);
END;
```